# convert String "30-MAR-07" to date object

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
dt = formatter.parse(temp[0]);
```

gives me the error

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "30-MAR-07"

Is there any way that I can format the given String to a Date object without having to write my own string splitting and translating-to-months-in-numerals methods?  Thanks

Comment: In what way do you expect "30-MAR-07" to match the format "mm/dd/yyyy"?

Comment: Why not read javadocs for SDF and then ask?

Answer (score 10):

Use correct format, as follows,

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
```

Answer (score 7):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` pattern is *completely* incorrect for "30-MAR-07". It's got the values in the wrong order, it uses the wrong separator, and the wrong month format. You want:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
```

You may also want to specify the locale, e.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.US);
```

I've checked that this works - at least on my machine :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this... `(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy")`

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(new Date("30-MAR-07")));
```

Comment: Jon isnt it going to convert the date 30-Mar-07 int to date object with the dd-MM-yy format..well i got the output when i did, sorry if i am missing something

Comment: You're calling the `Date` constructor and then formatting the result with the `SimpleDateFormatter`. The OP wants to *parse* the text using that `SimpleDateFormatter`, as per the question.

Comment: Ohh i see you meant it in this way... well i just did that so he can print it out once to see that its working... sorry if that seems the other way round..

Comment: Well in particular, you're relying on the `Date(String)` constructor being willing to handle that format, which seems a dubious assumption to me.

Comment: Ok.. that seems a real good piece of info...thanks i will keep that in mind.