# Java string to date with negative number

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert dates of the format

```
07/Mar/2004:16:56:39 -0800
```

to a date object. I'm not sure what that format's name even is but its used in tomcat access logs. Can someone please help me out?

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy:HH:mm:ss");
Date d = f.parse("07/Mar/2004:16:56:39 -0800"); // Throws exception.
System.out.println(d.getTime());
```

Comment: also a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11527451/642706) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/882420/642706), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21042484/642706) and many more.

Comment: Just for the record, this "negative number" is a [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601?oldformat=true#Time_offsets_from_UTC)

Answer (score 2):

The format string should match the input. In particular, the separator must match.

Also, your format string is missing the time zone part to match against the `-0800`.

Since your input uses English month name, you should explicitly specify that, e.g. using `Locale.US`.

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
Date d = f.parse("07/Mar/2004:16:56:39 -0800");
System.out.println(d);
```

Since I'm in Eastern time zone, that prints:

`Sun Mar 07 19:56:39 EST 2004`

---

You should however use the new `java.time` classes instead.

Since the input string has a time zone offset, that means you should parse the string to an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), using a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/uuuu:HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.parse("07/Mar/2004:16:56:39 -0800", f);
System.out.println(dt);
```

Output is:

`2004-03-07T16:56:39-08:00`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the time zone to your date format and change the format to your input string (`/` instead of `-`):

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
```

See the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: the `-` should be `/`

Comment: @luk2302 Yeah saw that too in the moment I answered.

Comment: f.parse("07/Mar/2004:16:56:39 /0800"); throws an exception though.

Comment: Still unparseable

Comment: And you need to set the appropriate Locale, too.

Comment: @newToScala why is there a `/` in front of `0800`?

Comment: How should "07/Mar/2004:16:56:39 -0800" be reformated to be parseable?

Comment: @newToScala `SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);`. You need to read the documentation.

Comment: I appreciate the help, and have looked at docs. This code still throws an exception:

```SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
    Date d = f.parse("07/Mar/2004:16:56:39 -0800");
    System.out.println(d.getTime());```

Comment: Don't use `SimpleDateFormat` and don't use `Date`. Use the new [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) instead: `OffsetDateTime.parse("07/Mar/2004:16:56:39 -0800", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/uuuu:HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US))`

Comment: @newToScala Because your format has `-` between date and month, and your string has `/`.

Comment: Doh. THat works now. THank you very much.

Comment: @bish OP says the string to parse is `07/Mar/2004:16:56:39 -0800`, so give a date format that matches that, don't tell OP to change the input. Down-voted until you fix answer.

Comment: @Andreas edited the slashes

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in the line:

`Date d = f.parse("07/Mar/2004:16:56:39 -0800");`

The format for the date is "dd-MMM-yyyy:HH:mm:ss". You need to replace the "/" with "-". Additionally, you need to surround your parse function with a try-catch block as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy:HH:mm:ss");
    Date d;
    try {
        d = f.parse("07-Mar-2004:16:56:39");
        System.out.println(d.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Check out this link to learn more about the SimpleDateFormat Class: 
http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-use-simpledateformat-class-formating-parsing-date-and-time/142

Comment: No. The format of the date uses `/` and has a time zone. The requirement is to find out the right format string so the given input can be parsed, not the other way around.